# How to dynamically get a name attribute of input type="text" and disable or enable it using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

can anyone help me with how to get a textfield name attribute and check in an array then disable or enable that field accordingly.below is my code

```
 $("input").each(function () {
    //alert();
    var check = $(this).attr('name');
    $("input[name='noListStrings[0]']").prop("disabled", true);
    if (check != undefined && $("input[name='" + check + "']").is(":hidden") == false) {
        for (var i = 0; i < yesListStrings.length; i++) {
            //alert("yesLoop");
            if (check == yesListStrings[i]) {
                alert("yesList");
                $("input[name='" + $(this).attr('name') + "']").attr("disabled", false);
            }
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < noListStrings.length; i++) {
            //alert("noLoop");
            if (check == noListStrings[i]) {
                alert("nolist");
                $("input[name='" + check + "']").attr("disabled", true);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I am checking the field name and if its present in that array i am disabling or enabling the field.
I have tried using `$.inArray(fieldname,myarr)` its not working.So please don't suggest me to use `$.inArray()`.

Comment: Can you make js fiddle of your code? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Why negative Voting may i know the reason??

Answer (score 0):

I usually add id to input in such cases. You can give id same as the name is. The $('#idname') provides a cleaner access.

```
$('input').each(function(){
    alert(this.name);
    //alert(this.id);
});
```

Comment: in that case you can use this.name in above code. But using id or class comes more handy in jquery

Comment: @Ashutous this.name is fine. but $("input[name='" + this.name+ "']").attr("disabled", true); is not working properly....                i want the name to be given dynamicaly as well.

Comment: @Srivishnurajan to enable the control $(this).attr('disabled',false) and to disable $(this).attr('disabled','disabled')

Comment: @Srivishnurajan ...Also answer for your datepicker question is use $("#startdate").datepicker('option', 'maxDate', 'dd/mm/yyyy')

Comment: @Srivishnurajan are you able to make your code work?

Comment: Thank u but i found the solution i required.  $("input[name='" + check + "']") had added ' unnecessarily so it was not working finally resolved.

Comment: $(this) is enough in this case, but it is your choice.

Answer (score 0):

I just wrote a piece of code for your problem. Try it. The logic is all the same loop in all inputs ^ then search the name in array & disable it.

```
yesListStrings = ['14','12'];

$('#click_me').on('click', function()
{
           $('input[type="text"]').each(function() 
            {
             if(jQuery.inArray(this.name,yesListStrings) != -1)
             {
                 $('input[name="'+this.name+'"]').attr('Disabled',true);
             }
    });                      
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/z59kmm96/

Comment: i tried this method earlier itself its not working with my code.

Comment: @Sri Can you provide a sample working Fiddle of your code? then we might be able to help more